# Are my components duplicated, or is this separation fine?

Tags: reactjs

I am building a ReactJS webapp, which feature a specific page where there is a lot of nullable information, that can or can't be displayed based on user rights (and the presence of the data).

I first started using many `if`s in a huge bloated component, and then started to extract into smaller child components, that could by themselves determine if they should return `null` or render something. However, I start to see that many components behave almost the same manner (a.k.a checking that the data passed via props is not empty, displaying based on user rights also passed via props and assigning a custom icon, not passed via props but in the child component itself).

I have about 10 components looking like this. Is this a code smell and should be more refactored ?

Here is an example:

Parent component

```
const InfoPerson = ({person}) => {

const {
 birthdate,
 first_name,
 last_name,
 confidential,
 address,
 state,
 permissions
 is_company
 /...
} = person

return (
 <Container>
  <PersonCompanyOwner isCompany={is_company}
                                firstName={first_name}
                                lastName={last_name}/> // Always visible, no user rights check

  <PersonAddress confidential={confidential}
                           canViewConfidential={permissions.can_view_confidential}
                           state={state}
                           address={address}/> // Does supplementary confidential check

  <PersonBirthdate confidential={confidential}
                            canViewConfidential={permissions.can_view_confidential}
                            date={birthdate}/> // Also confidential check


  </Row>
 </Container>
 )
}
```

Child component without check:

```
const PersonCompanyOwner = ({isCompany, firstName, lastName, job}) => {
  if (!isCompany || (!firstName && !lastName && !job)) {
    return null
  }

  return (
    <PersonItem icon={faUser}>
      {firstName && <div>{firstName}</div>}
      {lastName && <div>{lastName}</div>}
      {job && <div>{job}</div>}
    </PersonItem>
  )
}
```

Child with confidential check:

```
const PersonDate = ({ icon, date, confidential, canViewConfidential }) => {

  if (!date) {
    return null
  }

  return (
    <ConfidentialInformation isConfidential={confidential}
                             canViewConfidential={canViewConfidential}>
      <PersonItem icon={faCalendar}>
        <FormattedMessage id="date_format">
          {dateFormat => <span>{format(date, dateFormat)}</span>}
        </FormattedMessage>
      </PersonItem>
    </ConfidentialInformation>
  )
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a place for code review.

Comment: " I start to see that many components behave almost the same manner" so extract those into a separate part that's generic enough to be used by all.

Comment: @Mast actually I already did that (ConfidentialInformation and PersonItem where duplicated code before). The part that bugs me is the fact that the only difference in each component is which props it takes to determine if it should be visible or return null

Comment: This is a question for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ . The code that was posted doesn't seem to be duplicated.

Comment: @estus you are right, I'll ask these kind of questions there next time ! In the meantime I found the answer by myself.